# Symfony- Calling validation classl using variables

Tags: symfony

I am trying to do validation in symfony by using variables as shown below

```
 $call= 'Assert\\'.$k2;
                    //echo $k2.'-'.$item;
                    echo $call;
                   //exit;
                    $arrayConstraint = new $call($item);
                    //$arrayConstraint = new Assert\NotBlank(null);
                    $errors = $this->get('validator')->validate(
                        $arr_item,
                        $arrayConstraint
                    );
```

This code gives error:

Attempted to load class "NotBlank" from namespace "Assert".
Did you forget a "use" statement for "Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank"?

Whereas I am using the proper namespace(im including the class on top).

Whenevr i uncomment this line

```
 $arrayConstraint = new Assert\NotBlank(null);
```

and comment this

```
//$arrayConstraint = new $call($item);
```

it works perfectly fine.
I guess this has something to do with calling classes using variables. Any ideas for a workaround?
Any help will be deeply appreciated

Comment: I imagine that the code on top of that says somewhere in the beginning of the file:

    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

Comment: @MatíasNavarroCarter have already used that, still giving error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it, by adding the whole path(namespace) to the variable.

```
$call= "Symfony\\Component\\Validator\\Constraints\\".$k2;
```

This is working now.